# Why does friend class crash on static function call?

Tags: c++, friend-class

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CClass
{
private:
   friend class CFriend;
   static void privateFunc(){std::cout << "privateFunc" << std::endl;};
};

class CFriend
{
public:

   void privateFunc(){privateFunc();};
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   CFriend b;
   b.privateFunc();
   return 0;
}
```

This code compiles, but using the gcc-compiler or http://www.ideone.com/ the program crashes. Is that a compiler error or do I need to understand more about friend classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've created infinite recursion:

```
void privateFunc(){privateFunc();};
```

Use instead:

```
void privateFunc(){CClass::privateFunc();};
```

There's nothing wrong with friend declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You have the function called `privateFunc()` in CFriend class as well. This means when inside that function you call `privateFunc()` it will call itself (how should it know you mean the other class) thus entering a recursive infinite loop.

You mean

```
void privateFunc()
{
  CClass::privateFunc();
}
```

using `CClass::` to specify completely the name of the function you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Infinite recursion in your object, creating a **Stack Overflow** !!!

You must explicitely call your friend class :

```
void privateFunc(){CClass::privateFunc();};
```

Answer (score 2):

It is crashing because of stack overflow you would beed scope resolution to call static function

```
class CFriend
{
public:

   void privateFunc(){CClass::privateFunc();};
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a stack overflow from an infinitely recursive function.  CFriend::privateFunc is calling itself.  Change it to `void privateFunc() {CClass::privateFunc();}`

Scope distinctions, public, private, protected and friend, have not runtime consequences at all.  They are strictly for the compilier to decide what is legal or not.  You could `#define private public` and the resulting executable wouldn't change.